# I need to dynamically resize an array of objects

Tags: c++

I need to dynamically resize my array by 2 every time it fills up. It starts with a capacity of 2. This is what I've done (in main.cpp), but it gives me these errors: "warning: deleting array 'test'" and "error: incompatible types in assignment of 'ItemInfo*' to 'ItemInfo [cap]'".

```
ItemInfo test[cap];

//I have code here to open file, read from file, etc

if(itemCount >= cap){
    cap += 2;
    ItemInfo *temp;
    temp = new ItemInfo[cap];
    for(int i = 0; i < cap; i++){
        temp[i] = test[i];
    }
    delete[] test; //error here
    test = temp;   //error here
}
```

This is the class (in .hpp file):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

class ItemInfo {
private:
    int itemId;
    char description[40];
    double manCost;
    double sellPrice;
public:
    ItemInfo() {
        itemId = 0;
        *description = '\0';
        manCost = 0.0;
        sellPrice = 0.0;
    }
    void setItemId(const char *num);
    void setDescription(const char *cstr);
    void setManCost(const char *num);
    void setSellPrice(const char *num);
    int getItemId();
    const char *getDescription();
    double getManCost();
    double getSellPrice();
```

Comment: If  you're allowed to use it, use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). If not, look around the site a bit more and you'll find dozens of examples of how to do this with `new`.

Comment: As an aside, `cap += 2` is an unusual reallocation strategy, since reallocation is expensive.  `cap *= 2` would be more common.

Comment: the assignment asks to resize by 2, just so we can make sure we do it right

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you use `ItemInfo test[cap];`. Using this declaration results in `test` being saved on the stack. Therefore, it has constant size. Using `temp = new ItemInfo[cap];` dynamically allocates memory on the heap. This is the memory which you can also free. Thus, `test` and `temp` are different types and `test` cannot be freed. `ItemInfo *test = new ItemInfo[cap];` should work for you.

Also mind that there is another small mistake: You copy the first `cap` many values **after** increasing `cap` where the old `cap` should be used.

You could use `realloc` too **if `ItemInfo` is [trivially copyable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/TriviallyCopyable)** so that you do not need the loop to copy the data and temporarily use more memory than maybe needed. The code for using realloc would seem like

```
ItemInfo *test = (*ItemInfo) malloc(cap * sizeof(ItemInfo));
// use malloc here as realloc and new should not be mixed
[...]
if(itemCount >= cap){
    cap += 2;
    test = (*ItemInfo) realloc(test, cap * sizeof(ItemInfo));
}
```

As user4581301 mentioned you could also try to use `Vectors` if there is nothing specific against it.

Comment: Prefer to use the terms Automatic and Dynamic storage instead of stack and heap. You'll probably never see it done, but C++ don't need no stinking stacks or heaps.

Comment: @user4581301 Could you expain this a bit more? I mean, on the one hand, the C++ documentation seems to prefer these words and they are more high-level. On the other hand, the underlying fundamentals are stack and heap and these words are used by many other languages (and architecture-specific and theoretical aspects) making it easier to transfer knowledge from and to these cases.

Comment: *You could use realloc too* -- No.  If the class is not trivially-copyable, then `realloc` or `malloc` can't be used at all.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Sorry, I did not know that coming from C. Edited the answer, thanks for the info!

Comment: Not much to say, really. Stack and heap are implementation details and are almost always used for automatic and dynamic storage. I don't think I've seen a computer make it out of the lab that wasn't stack-and heap and I've never seen a C++ implementation with anything but stack  and heap, but the C++ Standard has completely abstracted both concepts away. This leads to something interesting: The implementation detail is more widely recognized than the more general abstraction. Take that Scott McCloud.

Comment: Side note: `malloc` and `realloc` are often used in the underbelly of `std::vector`. [placement `new`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new#Placement_new) is used to ensure proper construction.